# Unable to use RDKit in Jupyter or iPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rdkit

I want to use RDKit in a Jupyter environment. However, after I followed the procedure outlined in [this document](https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/08/17/getting-started-rdkit-and-jupyter/).

After following the process, including getting the kernel for jupyter, I tried to access RDKit and play with it.

```
(rdkit-test) [user] ~ $ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 07:22:35)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/rdkit-test/bin/python'
>>> import rdkit
>>>
[6]+  Stopped                 python
```

Right from test anaconda environment `rdkit-test`, it seems like I can access rdkit and test with it.

Now, I try to access it via iPython:

```
(rdkit-test) [user] ~ $ ipython
Python 3.8.7 (v3.8.7:6503f05dd5, Dec 21 2020, 12:45:15)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.17.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.executable
Out[2]: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8'

In [3]: import rdkit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6b72bd8913ab> in <module>
----> 1 import rdkit

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdkit'
```

I can't seem to access `rdkit`. I can also see that I am not in the write environment, from my `sys.executable` command.

The same problem I see in a Jupyter notebook:
[image]

How do I fix this and use RDKit in Jupyter or iPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use !pip install kora. Then, use import kora.install.rdkit.